# Trouble referring to a custom View in a layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-view

I am trying to refer to a custom View in the helloWorld XML layout but I get the following exception: 
Error inflating class acme.my.MyTextView.

However, I am able to instantiate the view and add it to the main content view manually. The custom View is built from it's own XML layout. How do I get this to work?

```
public class MyTextView extends LinearLayout {  

 MyTextView(Context context){
  super(context);

  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view,this);
 }

 MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
  super(context, attrs);

  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_text_view,this);
 }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

  <view class = "acme.my.MyTextView"
 android:id="@+id/myView" 
 android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
 />
```

Comment: @fredrick: usually, there is a 'caused by' exception below the one you cite that explains a bit more about what went wrong.

Comment: MyTextView(Context,AttributeSet)
I have a breakpoint at the top of the constructor though and it never gets hit.

Comment: Well I did this with very simple layouts and it seems to work. I'll figure out what is breaking it in the more complex layout.

Answer (score 1):

The constructors aren't public.
:(

Answer (score 0):

you have to call it like this

```
 <com.example.MyLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Also make your constructors public